# Error while designing Stack using ArrayList in java

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to find answer for question -
Design a stack that supports push, pop, top, and retrieving the minimum element in constant time.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackImplement{

     public static void main(String []args){
        MinStack obj = new MinStack();
        obj.push(-2);
        obj.push(0);
        obj.push(-3);
        
        System.out.println("Initaially stack :");
        obj.display();
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("After first getMin() = " + obj.getMin());
        
        obj.pop();
        
        System.out.println("Stack After pop() : ");
        obj.display();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("After second getMin() = " + obj.getMin());
        
     }
}

class MinStack {

    int top = -1;
    int min = (int)Math.pow(2,31);
    List<Integer> stack;
    
    public MinStack() {
         stack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    
    public void push(int val) {
        stack.add(val);
        top++;
    }
    
    public void pop() {
        stack.remove(top);
        top--;
    }
    
    public int top() {
        int x = stack.get(top);
        return x;
    }
    
    public int getMin() {
        for(int x:stack){
            if(x<min)   
                min = x;
        }
        return min;
    }
    
    public void display(){
        for(int x:stack)
            System.out.print(x +" ");
    }
}
```

I have written above program, but facing issue in 'getMin()' method. First time 'getMin()' gives correct output.But after 'pop()', the 'getMin()' method should return ans as '-2'. It is given wrong answer as below :

```
Initaially stack :
-2 0 -3 
After first getMin() = -3
Stack After pop() : 
-2 0 
After second getMin() = -3
```

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: You are saving your min value in a field and only update it if you find something smaller. So once -3 is set it will never be set to anything higher ever because of `if(x<min)`. But honestly, saving the min value in a class filed seems like bad design for this case. You would probably be better of removing it and always calculating the value on demand in the getMin method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getMin` needs to reset `min` to `(int)Math.pow(2,31)` aka `Integer.MAX_VALUE` each time it is called.